# How to force Ansible 'shell' task to change state with 'changed_when' condition?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am running script with Ansible task which installs some repositories and my goal is to show changed state when running change mode to notify, that script will run if check mode will not be activated.

My first task is to check existence of this repository:

```yaml
- name: Check repository existence
  become: yes
  shell: yum repolist -v | grep some-repository
  register: repo_exists
  check_mode: false
  failed_when: false
  changed_when: false
```

This task should run even in check mode, so I can operate with **repo_exists** variable in next tasks. This works fine when I run Ansible in check mode, this is the output:

```json
"msg": {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "yum repolist -v | grep some-repository",
    "delta": "0:00:02.022965",
    "end": "2023-06-12 13:06:54.611504",
    "failed": false,
    "failed_when_result": false,
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2023-06-12 13:06:52.588539",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

My script should run only when repository is missing:

```yaml
- name: Add repository
  become: yes
  shell: echo "install repository"
  changed_when: "repo_exists.rc != 0"
  when: "repo_exists.rc != 0"
```

`when` condition should ensure, task will run only if **rc** is not zero, which means, repository was not in repolist.
`changed_when` should show state **CHANGED** even in check mode **rc** is not zero.

Instead of expected result, I can see state **skipping**:

```json
{
  "changed": false,
  "cmd": "echo \"install repository\"",
  "delta": null,
  "end": null,
  "msg": "Command would have run if not in check mode",
  "rc": 0,
  "start": null,
  "stderr": "",
  "stderr_lines": [],
  "stdout": "",
  "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I do not understand, why task is in skipping state and what I do wrong? Is this right way how to see shell task in change state when running check mode?

Answer (score 1):

> *I do not understand, why task is in skipping state*

As already mentioned within the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *`"msg": "Command would have run if not in check mode"`*

it is because you are [Using check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode). If you really want to [prevent check mode on tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks) you would need to use

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Check repository existence
    shell:
      cmd: yum repolist -v | grep not-existing
    register: repo_exists
    # Since it is a reporting task
    # which needs to deliver a result in any case
    failed_when: repo_exists.rc != 0 and repo_exists.rc != 1
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false

  - name: Add repository
    shell:
      cmd: "echo {{ repo_exists.stdout_lines }}"
    when: repo_exists.rc != 0
    changed_when: repo_exists.rc != 0
    check_mode: false
```

```sh
ansible-playbook main.yml --check -v
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check repository existence] ************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  cmd: yum repolist -v | grep not-existing
  delta: '0:00:05.598043'
  end: '2023-06-13 18:00:31.862501'
  failed_when_result: false
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2023-06-13 18:00:26.264458'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [Add repository] ************************
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  cmd: echo []
  delta: '0:00:00.014928'
  end: '2023-06-13 18:00:32.318558'
  msg: ''
  rc: 0
  start: '2023-06-13 18:00:32.303630'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: '[]'
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

PLAY RECAP ***********************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1
```

But keep in mind, that wouldn't be a Dry Run for the `shell` module anymore.

---

> *This will run it every time - not required. My goal is to show if script will run out of check mode - so change state will be shown.*

What you are requesting is that the `shell` command or script itself needs to know first if it is running in `check_mode: true` and second behave different if so. In other words, your script would need to support `check_mode`. Whereby this is something which is the `shell` module doing [partially](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#attribute-check_mode), it can't act for or on behalf of your commands and scripts.

> *Maybe I understand it wrongly and my defined output is not possible to implement?*

You would need to implement at least something like

```yaml
  - name: Add repository
    shell:
      cmd: "{{ ansible_check_mode | lower }} || echo {{ repo_exists.stdout_lines }}"
    changed_when: "repo_exists.rc != 0"
    when: repo_exists.rc != 0
    check_mode: false
```

to make the command aware of `check_mode`, let it run or not and resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Add repository] ***************
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  cmd: true || echo []
  delta: '0:00:00.023104'
  end: '2023-06-15 11:00:00.550097'
  msg: ''
  rc: 0
  start: '2023-06-15 11:00:00.526993'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [Add repository] ***************
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  cmd: false || echo []
  delta: '0:00:00.014626'
  end: '2023-06-15 11:00:00.098413'
  msg: ''
  rc: 0
  start: '2023-06-15 11:00:00.083787'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: '[]'
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

As this seems to become already very and over complex you might need to overthink what you really trying to achieve. It seems like a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) and there are already modules which are doing the work, just adding a repository [`yum_repository` module – Add or remove YUM repositories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html) with f[ull `check_mode` support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_repository_module.html#attribute-check_mode) or for updating [`ini_file` module – Tweak settings in INI files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html). There is absolut no need for a "CHECK ADD IF ONLY WHEN" or to re-implement already existing functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This will run it every time - not required. My goal is to show if script will run out of check mode - so change state will be shown. This is quiet unclean if the script will run. Also, skipping message is seen, but read and check every skip reason is quiet not best option I think. I would expect to see it in RECAP, how many changes will be performed.

Comment: From docs: **changed_when** - This lets you determine, based on return codes or output, whether a change should be reported in Ansible statistics and whether a handler should be triggered or not. Also, good example is [Ansible changed_when and failed_when examples](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-changed_when-and-failed_when-examples/). Maybe I understand it wrongly and my defined output is not possible to implement?